# How to make munin graph (derive or counter) not per second?

Tags: munin, graph

I have values:

```
10:00 - 505
11:00 - 507
12:00 - 510
13:00 - 525
```

and i want get graph:

```
11:00 - 2
12:00 - 3
13:00 - 15
```

but have per second(munin run every 5 minutes):

```
11:00 - 2/300
12:00 - 3/300
13:00 - 15/300
```

how i can make graph per hour?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How you do this depends on what type of data source you're dealing with.  On a host that has the plugin for the graph, run `munin-run <plugin> config` and look for the `type` attribute of its fields.

If the fields are of type COUNTER or DERIVE, you can just set the graph's [graph_period](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/graph_period) attribute to `minute` or `hour` for the graph in question.  For example, my mail server isn't tremendously busy, so it makes more sense to show its graphs in messages per minute instead of messages per second.  I do that with the following host definition in `munin.conf`:

```
[mailserver.our.tld]
    <snip other config>
    sendmail_mailstats.graph_period minute
```

(This is also [a munin FAQ](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/faq#Q:CanImakeagraphshowvaluesperminuteinsteadofpersecond).)

If the fields are of type GAUGE or ABSOLUTE, you'll have to use the [cdef](http://munin-monitoring.org/wiki/fieldname.cdef) attribute to adjust the values accordingly.  You'll probably also have to change the graph_vlabel attribute to match your new scaling.  An example of that is the `nutups2__runtime` plugin, which reports UPS runtime in seconds.  I prefer to see it in minutes, so I have the following host definition in `munin.conf`:

```
[upshost.our.tld]
    <snip other config>
    nutups2_ups_runtime.battery.cdef battery,60,/
    nutups2_ups_runtime.graph_vlabel Minutes
```

Comment: thanks, `var.cdef var,300,*` work perfect.